# Swift class member that is a lambda

Tags: swift

I have a class and I want a member variable of the class to be of type lambda function. This lambda will be set in one of the functions of that class.

```
class MyCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {

var onCollectionViewItemSelected:{(i:Int)->Void}


func setLambda(lambda:(i:Int)->Void) {
   self.onCollectionViewItemSelected = lambda
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.onCollectionViewItemSelected(indexPath.row)
}

}
```

This gives compiler errors. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This was the correct syntax

```
var onCollectionViewItemSelected:(i:Int)->Void = {(i:Int) in}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is little reason to define a `setlambda` function as you can just use assignment to a property or to a computed property.  Also, as it stands, you don't appear to be initializing the 'callback' which suggests that it's type might best be an optional - or not, with a required initial value

```
class MyCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {

  var itemSelectedCallback = { (i:Int) -> Void in return } // type inferred

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, 
      didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    itemSelectedCallback (indexPath.row)
  }
}
```